# Script recorre URL's, recoge información y la guarda en archivo

Tags: php, script, curl

tengo un problema con un script que no soy capaz de hacer.

Hace mucho tiempo que no toco PHP (demasiado en realidad) y necesito hacer un script que recorra una serie de URL's, recoja unos datos de una tabla y los guarde en un documento.

El funcionamiento, básicamente, es:

Empieza el bucle, entra en la url https://www.ejemplo.com/000001/, carga los datos que esta contiene, recoge información de una tabla determinada (con id #tablaEjemplo), la pasa a una array (supongo), de este array selecciono otros datos (nombre, dirección y mail) y esta información la guarda en un fichero externo (txt/csv).

Una vez hecho esto pasa a la siguiente dirección https://www.ejemplo.com/000001/ y hace lo mismo... y así hasta un número determinado de veces.

El fichero resultante sería algo así como:

https://www.ejemplo.com/000001

Nombre

Direccion

Mail

https://www.ejemplo.com/000002

Nombre

Direccion

Mail

etc

```php
<?php
  //Script recorre X URL (000001-000100), recoge determinados datos (nombre, direcion, mail) y los guarda en un archivo
  $userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0';
  $valores = [];

  for ($idempresa = 000001; $idempresa < 000100; $idempresa++): //Bucle for para recorrer X paginas de una URL (891721-899999)
      $url = "https://www.ejemplo.com/".$idempresa."/";
      echo $url;
      //$url2 = $url." #tablaEjemplo > tbody > tr > td"; //URL con los parametros añadidos


  //function get_content_with_curl($html) //Definimos la función cURL
  //{
      $ch = curl_init(); //Inicia cURL
      $archivo = fopen("./datos.txt", "a") or die("ERROR: No ha sido posible abrir el archivo. Revisa su nombre y sus permisos."); //Abrimos el archivo
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$url"); //Configura cURL con la URL deseada
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Configura cURL para devolver el resultado como cadena
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //Configura cURL para que no verifique el certificado
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent); //Configura el user-agent
      $info = curl_exec($ch); //Establece una sesión cURL y asigna la información a la variable $info
      curl_close($ch); //Cierra cURL

      //Recorremos el array y vamos guardando en un txt cada unos de los valores
      foreach ($valores as $datos) {
          fwrite($archivo, PHP_EOL ."$datos"); //Escribimos en el archivo los diferentes valores que se recogieron de la url
      }
      fclose($archivo); //Cerramos el archivo para evitar errores
  //}

  //Llamada a la función
  //Convierte la información de la URL en cadena
  //$html = get_content_with_curl($url);

  //Se imprime lo que obtuvimos en esa variable
  //echo $html;

      var_dump($info); //Devuelve la información

  endfor; //Cerramos bucle for para evitar problemas
```

Esto es todo lo que yo fui capaz de sacar, además de muchos pedazos de código que no sirven para nada y un buen dolor de cabeza.

Espero haberme explicado bien, si alguien me puede ayudar tendrá mi eterna gratitud!

Answer (score 0):

No se cual es el error que te tira pero puedo notar que a la hora de crear el link con el $idEmpresa tienes una / de mas antes del id, deberia ser

`$url = "https://www.ejemplo.com/".$idempresa."/";`

Comment: Gracias por responder tan rápido, la / de más fue un descuido al transcribir el código.

El problema no es que me devuelva o no algún error... el problema real es que no tengo ni idea de lo que estoy haciendo.

No se convertir ese trozo de código con cURL y poco más en el objetivo.

Comment: para eso no te puedo ayudar mucho, todas las veces que necesite hacer web scrapping las hice con node.js y puppeteer

Comment: Gracias, es la primera vez que hago algo de webscrapping/crawlers. Puedes mostrarme algo parecido a lo que necesito con node.js y puppeteer? Tal vez así me oriente mejor

Comment: https://youtu.be/8BorxvBF8Js este video me sirvio mucho la primera vez

Comment: Gracias! Me pongo con ello ahora mismo! A ver si saco adelante esto :)